# i am trying to use rest api but don't understand where,why and when i should use this

Tags: api, rest

What is the purpose of rest API and where it should be used how can i know that in this part of website i should use rest API any one can tell me in simple words why,where and how can in implement that technology ?

Comment: Many times when i apply for a job mostly asked me about rest API there are a lot of tutorials but i can't understand about that. That is clear that rest API work with systems internally and there response will be in Json OR XML format

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be not througout and lacking in precision, but it may do.

REST API means serving app (website) API through HTTP requests (mainly)
Thats simple/silly explanation.

Better one is here:
[What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

About when to use it... well.. that depends.
I guess common use case is when you want to expose some part of data/functionality of your site for third party developers. Then you may define URL under which you would return data in json or xml or....